# comparing IP address through pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of IP addresses. And I am trying to match it with an IP address which I am getting as part of the header. If the returned IP matches with any one IP in the array I am passing a success message otherwise a failure

Here is what I have and it is not working

```
var redirectIPExcludeList = [213.235.0.105,213.235.0.106,86.12.149.50,79.173.148.50,207.164.206.66]
var returnedIp = 1.0.0.255

for(var i =0; i<=redirectIPExcludeList.length; i++){
    if(returnedIp == redirectIPExcludeList[i]){
        alert('perfect match')
    }else{
        alert('falied')
    }
}
```

I somewhat have an idea that maybe I need to split these IP to be able to compare them but not able to get the concept correctly

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/MeR9k/

Comment: The first two lines are syntax errors...

Comment: It's not working because expressing an IP address like that is a syntax error, as is being reported in the browser error console.

Comment: typos aside, anyone can by-pass your IP filter because it's not done server-side...

Comment: When working with JavaScript in the browser, keep and eye on the console in the browser's DevTools. Your jsFiddle demo throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare them as strings

```
if("1.0.0.255" == "213.235.0.105" )
```

Try it now.

```
var redirectIPExcludeList = ["213.235.0.105","213.235.0.106","86.12.149.50","79.173.148.50","207.164.206.66","1.0.0.255"]
var returnedIp = "1.0.0.255"

for(var i =0; i< redirectIPExcludeList.length; i++){
    if(returnedIp == redirectIPExcludeList[i]){
        alert('perfect match : '+ redirectIPExcludeList[i] + ' = ' +returnedIp )

    }else{
        alert('falied : '+ redirectIPExcludeList[i] + ' != ' +returnedIp)
    }

}
```

Comment: @hector--thats what i am trying to do...now i have them stored in an array as strings..but seems to me its not really doing any good

Comment: I just tried your code from http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/MeR9k/ , and it works just fine. I edited a bit and ran it... give it a try again and let me know.

Comment: @Hector--I dont see any change in the fiddle..Did you happen to save them? For me its not working

Comment: @Hector--sorry I missed your solution. It works perfectly fine. Really sorry about not paying attention to your solution. Thanks again for helping me understand the issue

Answer (score 2):

Declare all the IPs as strings in the array and in returnedIp (wrap them into "").

```
var redirectIPExcludeList = ["213.235.0.105","213.235.0.106","86.12.149.50","79.173.148.50","207.164.206.66"];
var returnedIp = "1.0.0.255";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *no `dataType` to evaluate `IP` address/ number with 4 decimal digits* .  So make them as **`string`** datatype  like

```
var redirectIPExcludeList = ["213.235.0.105","213.235.0.106","86.12.149.50","79.173.148.50","207.164.206.66"]
var returnedIp = "1.0.0.255"
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeR9k/6/)

Comment: @Praveen--if you take an IP from the list and try to compare you will notice it is not really working. It is giving failure message regardless

Comment: @soum no, string looks for the exact match.  `1.0.0.255` is not in array so it fails in all if statement, whereas check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeR9k/7/)

Comment: @Praveen-- it is weird, the new fiddle that you gave still alerts the failed message. I see what you did though. But is it working on your end? Are you getting a success?